# NavigationLink issue: Cannot convert value of type '...' to expected argument type '...'

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I am trying to create a navigation screen that will give two buttons - one that goes to a fun little game and one that goes to a part that shows me random images. I've found the NavigationLink function and I can get it to work generally, but I'm getting an error that I don't understand. I've looked up a number of solutions, but none that use NavigationLink, so I'm not sure how to implement what I've read.

One of the buttons should navigate to the game, but the NavigationLink is giving the error: "Cannot convert value of type 'GameViewModel.Type' to expected argument type 'GameViewModel'"

If I try and remove "viewModel: GameViewModel" and instead replace it with a normal "choice: String", it instead gives the error: "Missing argument for parameter 'viewModel' in call" and then suggests a fix that just puts "viewModel: GameViewModel" right back as it is below.

What I don't understand is what this is trying to tell me. All I'm trying to do is have the NavigationView go to start the game, which is from the "struct GameView: View {" line at top. It seems like there is some sort of issue with the "var viewModel: GameViewModel", but I've tried putting that in other places and just can't get it to work.

If I remove the NavigationLink parts and just have it start the game, it works. If I remove the NavigationLink parts and just have it show me the pictures, it works. It's just this error that I don't understand.

I'd appreciate any help! This forum has really helped me over the past week or so, which has been so great!

Updated code:

```
import SwiftUI
import Foundation

struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var score = 0
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            Image("Clouds")
                .overlay(
                VStack {
                    NavigationLink(destination: ResultView2(choice: "Menu2")) {
                            Image("Menu2")
                    }
                    NavigationLink(destination: GameView(viewModel: GameViewModel(Engine.self as! Engine, storage: Storage.self as! Storage, stateTracker: StateTracker.self as! StateTracker))) {
                            Image("Menu")
                    }
                })
        }
    }

struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView()
    }
}
}

struct GameView: View {
    @ObservedObject var viewModel: GameViewModel
    @State var showMenu = false
    var body: some View {
        VStack(alignment: .center, spacing: 16) {
            Header(score: viewModel.state.score, bestScore: viewModel.bestScore, menuAction: {
                self.showMenu.toggle()
            }, undoAction: {
                self.viewModel.undo()
            }, undoEnabled: self.viewModel.isUndoable)
            GoalText()
            Board(board: viewModel.state.board, addedTile: viewModel.addedTile)
            Moves(viewModel.numberOfMoves)
        }
        .frame(minWidth: .zero,
               maxWidth: .infinity,
               minHeight: .zero,
               maxHeight: .infinity,
               alignment: .center)
            .background(Color.gameBackground)
            .background(Menu())
            .background(GameOver())
            .edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all)
    }
}
extension GameView {
private func Menu() -> some View {
    EmptyView().sheet(isPresented: $showMenu) {
        MenuView(newGameAction: {
            self.viewModel.reset()
            self.showMenu.toggle()
        }, resetScoreAction: {
            self.viewModel.eraseBestScore()
            self.showMenu.toggle()
        })
    }
}

private func GameOver() -> some View {
    EmptyView().sheet(isPresented: $viewModel.isGameOver) {
        GameOverView(score: self.viewModel.state.score, moves: self.viewModel.numberOfMoves) {
            self.viewModel.reset()
        }
    }
}
}

struct ResultView2: View {
    var choice: String
    var body: some View {
        Text("You chose Menu2")
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your example, you are passing `GameViewModel`, which appears to be a `class type`. However, `GameView(viewModel:)` takes a variable of the type `GameViewModel` or an instance of `GameViewModel`.

**1. First One**

In this case, we're passing an instance of `GameViewModel`, so the code would look like this:

You need to change

```
NavigationLink(destination: GameView(viewModel: GameViewModel)) {
```

to

```
NavigationLink(destination: GameView(viewModel: GameViewModel())) {
```

The above solution will solve the problem, but since you might want to use your `GameViewModel` instance (access or/and set values) in your parent view `ContentView`(in this case) before passing it to your child view `GameView` (in this case), it is better to have an instance variable of `GameViewModel` stored in your parent view and then pass it to your child view.
To demonstrate this:

**2. Second Option**

// In your `ContentView`, create this instance variable of type `GameViewModel`:

```
@@bservedObject var gameViewModel = GameViewModel()
```

// And pass it to `GameView` like this:

```
 NavigationLink(destination: GameView(viewModel: gameViewModel) {
```

Comment: That makes sense. Thanks y'all! I got it to work. The only thing I don't understand now is that the code works, but for some reason it's skipping the Navigation menu and jumping straight into the NavigationLink item we just fixed. It is supposed to show the picture of clouds with two menu buttons - the first goes to the one we fixed above, the second goes to the other part. Instead, the app just jumps straight to the one we fixed above. There is no error shown anywhere. I did not change any other lines of code other than the above.

Comment: The described behavior shouldn't occur, Can u share (again) your code, provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: I added in the code. I left it out at first because I'm using a little game I found online doing research to learn. Since I didn't make it I wasn't sure if I should paste it, but it's online anyways. It's some game called "2048". There are some other .swift files that it links to as well, but no errors in any of those and the code I pasted above is for the main view of the game.

Comment: I was forced to add in some extra stuff in the NavigationLink, but it all works with no errors, just that it jumps straight to the game and doesn't go to the navigation menu.

Comment: If it helps, this is the game I found. The author gives permission to use it to learn, so I'm using it until I figure out this part and then figured in the future I'll try making my own game. https://github.com/caiobzen/2048-swiftui

Comment: Thinking about it, should I start a new topic since this is now a new and different question?